# A mapped function's arguments cannot be used in client-side operations in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to export table for each point. I hope:

1. Each point are sampled with every images;
2. The return-FeatureCollections of 1. are iterated to tables;
3. Each table are exported.

My goal is, if I have three points in my pointset, I export three tables. like...

[image]

Code executes successfully but when I try to run the task to complete the process I get following error,

> A mapped function's arguments cannot be used in client-side operations in GEE

My code...

```
var park = ee.FeatureCollection("users/park"),
point2015 = ee.FeatureCollection("users/point2015");

var dataname = ee.String('Image NASA/GPM_L3/IMERG_V06/');
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/GPM_L3/IMERG_V06")
              .select(['precipitationCal'])
              .filterDate('2015-02-23', '2015-02-25')
              //.filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index','20150223000000'))
              .filterBounds(park)
              ;
print('dataset',dataset);

var pointset = point2015
           .select(['UTM_time_','event_id'])
           .filter(ee.Filter.eq('UTM_time_','20150224190000'))
          ;
print('pointset',pointset);


pointset.evaluate(function(points){

  points = ee.FeatureCollection(points);

  points.map(function(point){
    var ft = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List([]));

    var fill = function(img, ini) {

      var inift = ee.FeatureCollection(ini);

      var ft2 = img.sampleRegions({
        collection:point,
        //,
        properties:ee.List(['event_id','UTM_time_']),
        scale:30
      });

      var date = img.date().format();
  
      var id = img.getString('system:index');
  
      var ft3 = ft2.map(function(f){return f.set("id", id)});
  
      return inift.merge(ft3);
  
    };

  // Iterates over the ImageCollection
  var point_precipitation = ee.FeatureCollection(dataset.iterate(fill, ft));

  var a4 = Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: point_precipitation,
    folder:'point_pre_2015_a',
    description: 'point_pre_2015_a',
    fileFormat: 'CSV'
  });

  return point_precipitation;
    
  });

});
        
        
  //var a3 = pointset.evaluate(a1);
        
  Map.addLayer(park, {color: "black"}, "roi");
```

Link of *point2015* and *park*:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1UMqtTqTk1DGjWW4b1c7BrMI3010M1mFu?usp=sharing

Link of my code:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/72d09c610df4171d003dadf02b85ca63

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Actually, I have lots of points are waiting for being sampled. So I hope tables can be export in evaluate function.

Comment: Also, please share your assets too, so the script can run for other's than you.

Comment: I have added code and shared my shapefile. The script can run for others.